# Reading Powerpoint SmartArt in Java

Tags: apache-poi, powerpoint, openxml

I found Apache POI doesn't support reading SmartArt component.
(Am I right?)

So I tried [Aspose.Slides](http://www.aspose.com/java/powerpoint-component.aspx) and it worked.
But the trial version has critical restriction.
(can't get text has length over 5 characters)

Can anybody help?

Comment: What's your objective in reading the Smart Art?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read SmartArt with docx4j/pptx4j.

To see how it is represented, upload your sample pptx to webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html  then click through into the /ppt/diagrams parts.

There is also a document [Creating SmartArt with docx4j](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/raw/master/docs/Creating%20SmartArt%20with%20docx4j.docx), though please note this is an advanced topic (and you are largely on your own).

Answer (score 0):

@Shinbop,

I have observed your requirements and suggest you to please try using latest Aspose.Slides for .NET 18.11 on your end using [valid Aspose.Slides license](https://docs.aspose.com/display/slidesnet/Licensing) while using API. If you use API without license, it shall pose certain restrictions including limited text extraction from shapes inside presentation. You can please visit [this official documentation section link](https://docs.aspose.com/display/slidesnet/Adding%2C+Formatting+and+Manipulating+SmartArt) concerning to SmartArt shapes.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.